# CDK Cloud Formation not waiting for addDependency to complete

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-simple-email-service

I am building a CDK stack and new to CDK. I am trying to create a Simple Email Service (SES) `ConfigurationSet` and then an `EmailIdentity`, which requires the `ConfigurationSet` to already be created. When I run them the cloud formation step for `EmailIdentity` fails due to the Configuration Set not completed yet. I thought if I added `EmailIdentityConstructor.node.adddDependency(ConfigurationSet)` that cloud formation would wait, but adding this to the CDK seemed to have no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Logically, this should be a single stack. It's one set of SES resources I am trying to create.

```
    const ConfigurationSetConstructor = new ses.ConfigurationSet(this, 'email-bi-config-set', {
      sendingEnabled: true,
      reputationMetrics: false,
      suppressionReasons: ses.SuppressionReasons.BOUNCES_AND_COMPLAINTS,
      tlsPolicy: ses.ConfigurationSetTlsPolicy.REQUIRE,
    });

    ConfigurationSetConstructor.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);

    const myConfigSet = ses.ConfigurationSet.fromConfigurationSetName(this, id, 'email-bi-config-set');

    const EmailIdentityConstructor = new ses.EmailIdentity(this, 'email-identity', {
      identity: ses.Identity.domain(domain),
      configurationSet: myConfigSet,
      feedbackForwarding: true,
      mailFromDomain: domain,
    });

    EmailIdentityConstructor.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
    EmailIdentityConstructor.node.addDependency(ConfigurationSetConstructor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are creating the config set and then importing it in the same stack. If you synthesize the stack, you'll notice that CDK is not adding the `DependsOn` between the resources. I'm not sure why that is happening in your case.

But you can simplify the implementation to allow CloudFormation to infer the dependencies.

```
    const myConfigSet = new ses.ConfigurationSet(this, 'email-bi-config-set', {
      sendingEnabled: true,
      reputationMetrics: false,
      suppressionReasons: ses.SuppressionReasons.BOUNCES_AND_COMPLAINTS,
      tlsPolicy: ses.ConfigurationSetTlsPolicy.REQUIRE,
    });

    myConfigSet.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);

    const EmailIdentityConstructor = new ses.EmailIdentity(this, 'email-identity', {
      identity: ses.Identity.domain(domain),
      configurationSet: myConfigSet,
      feedbackForwarding: true,
      mailFromDomain: domain,
    });

    EmailIdentityConstructor.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
```

With this implementation, CDK will create a `Ref` in the template and automatically infer the dependency between both.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware I could call the configuration set constructor itself!